# on click is not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a table and want to get an id on a td click. The data is population through an ajax call and I an want an id on when delete is clicked. So its on the fly the elements are added.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/getUsers,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $.each(data, function (index, result) {
                $("<tr></tr>").attr("id",result.user_id+"userTr").appendTo("#userTBody");
                $("<td></td>").attr("id",result.user_id+"userName").appendTo("#"+result.user_id+"userTr");
                $("#"+result.user_id+"userName").html(result.username);
                $("<td></td>").attr("id",result.user_id).appendTo("#"+result.user_id+"userTr");
                $("#"+result.user_id).html('Delete');
                $("#"+result.user_id).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                $("#"+result.user_id).addClass("delete");
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('err')
        }
    });

$('.delete').on('click', function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

I have also tried with this.id but nothing happens.

Comment: Yep, read the post linked above, you want to switch your notation from delete.on click to document.on click '.delete'

Comment: @Tushar, I have a question why with the document .on instead of simple $('delete').on? because of dynamically created elements in a DOM?

Comment: @Java_NewBie Please read the answers on the stated question. Also read about [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Comment: Please don't answer such obvious dupe questions if you can't add anything to existing answers, close it instead.